# How to insert a video with gtkmm

Tags: c++, c++11, gtk, c++14, gtkmm

i am looking for a way to insert a video in my software developped in C++ using the gtkmm library. But i did not see any documentation on this.

Does someone know how to put a video with the GTKmm library ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: GTK is a GUI widget toolkit. It has no media playing functionality. GTKmm is not some mysterious, closed source, black box library. It's free software, and its documentation is freely available. If you don't see something there, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you but do you know if it is possible to play a video with GTKmm ?

Comment: What part of "GTKmm has no media playing functionality" is unclear?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Look up GStreamer.

Answer (score 3):

gtkmm itself is not a multimedia framework. However, you can use it together with multimedia frameworks, e.g. GStreamer (or gstreamermm, which is c++ wrapper for GStreamer). Here is an example of simple multimedia player written in gtkmm and gstreamermm: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gstreamermm/tree/examples/ogg_player_gtkmm